# transform a dataframe in R, re organize according to one variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe called data1 of this type:

```
individual location type
1       site1  1 
2       site2  3
3       site3  2 
4       site4  3
5       site5  1 
6       site2  4 
7       site5  2
```

I would like to transform the data above into rows (observations) for distinct sites, and count the number of types for each site, and obtain the following:

```
location type1 type2 type3 type4
site1   1   0   0   0  
site2   0   0   1   1  
site3   0   1   0   0  
site4   0   0   1   0 
site5   2   1   0   0
```

how do I create a dataset with the format above ?
(the above is simplified, my original data are 2500 individuals and 400 locations)

Answer (score 1):

Try this `tidyverse` approach which is close to want you want. You can reshape your data to long, obtain the values for your dataframe and then reshape to wide to obtain the expected result. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Code
df %>% 
  #Mutate type
  mutate(type=paste0('type',type)) %>%
  #Mutate number of types
  group_by(location,type) %>%
  mutate(N=n()) %>% select(-individual) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = type,values_from=N) %>%
  replace(is.na(.),0) %>% select(sort(current_vars()))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   location [5]
  location type1 type2 type3 type4
  <chr>    <int> <int> <int> <int>
1 site1        1     0     0     0
2 site2        0     0     1     1
3 site3        0     1     0     0
4 site4        0     0     1     0
5 site5        1     1     0     0
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
df <- structure(list(individual = 1:7, location = c("site1", "site2", 
"site3", "site4", "site5", "site2", "site5"), type = c(1L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Comment: thanks for your reply , it works. now, I have an additional related question: some individuals in the same location belong to the same type. Therefore I modified your data to:
 , with 2 individuals of type 1 in site 5. i get instead <NULL> where there are no values, tried different options to replace the NA but did not work.

Comment: @MariaEugeniaD'Amato Hi Maria Eugenia, in that case you should play around the group by statement and summarize the counts. Also if you find this answer helpful, you could accept it by clicking the tick on the left side in this answer it is up to you and in that way you encourage people to continue helping others :)

Comment: I found a simple, not too elegant solution: subsetting the file by types, then grouping by location and countng them:

Comment: data_type1 %>% group_by(location) %>% summarize(count=n())

Answer (score 0):

In `base R`, we can just use `table`

```
table(df[-1])
#     type
#location 1 2 3 4
#   site1 1 0 0 0
#   site2 0 0 1 1
#   site3 0 1 0 0
#   site4 0 0 1 0
#   site5 1 1 0 0
```

---

Or using `pivot_wider` with `values_fn`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
     select(-individual) %>%
     pivot_wider(names_from = type, values_from = type, values_fn = length, 
         values_fill = 0)
# A tibble: 5 x 5
#  location   `1`   `3`   `2`   `4`
#  <chr>    <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1 site1        1     0     0     0
#2 site2        0     1     0     1
#3 site3        0     0     1     0
#4 site4        0     1     0     0
#5 site5        1     0     1     0
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(individual = 1:7, location = c("site1", "site2", 
"site3", "site4", "site5", "site2", "site5"), type = c(1L, 3L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```